# I am creating a vue custom input component but the values ​are not being reflected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a custom input component using Vue 3. I'm trying to make the value of parent's data change when the value of input changes, but it doesn't work as intended.

Code **:**

CustomInput.vue

```
<template>
  <input :type="type" :value="value" @input="onChange" />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "custom-input",
  props: {
    type: String,
    value: String,
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event: Event) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
      this.$emit("input", target.value);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Form.vue

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onsubmit">
    <h2>Bucket Login</h2>
    <CustomInput type="text" :value="id" v-model="id" placeholder="ID" />
    <CustomInput
      type="password"
      :value="password"
      v-model="password"
      placeholder="PASSWORD"
    />
    <CustomButton>Login</CustomButton>
    <p @click="moveJoin">Join</p>
  </form>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton.vue";
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "login-form",
  components: {
    CustomButton,
    CustomInput,
  },
  data: () => ({
    id: "",
    password: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    onsubmit() {
      console.log(this.id); // result => undefined
    },
    moveJoin() {
      this.$router.push("/join");
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

If you execute `onSubmit` after entering a value in `customInput`, the value of `this.id` is undefined.

Comment: In Vue3, props and event for custom `v-model` are named `modelValue` and `$emit('update:modelValue')`, try with this :)